# Azure SQL Database replicated in two zones

Tags: sql-server, azure

Windows Azure sometimes has problems, for example, now, at 3.37 AM UTC:

[image]

Their "West US SQL Databases" and "West US Websites" are both down:

> - We are experiencing an issue with SQL Database in the West US
>     sub-region that began at 3:07 AM UTC. A subset of customers may be
>     unable to access their SQL databases. We are actively investigating.
>     Further updates will be published to keep you apprised of the
>     situation.
> - We are experiencing an issue with Web Sites in the West US sub-region
>     that began as early as 3:04 AM UTC on 6/11. A subset of customers may
>     be unable to create or manage their web sites. We are actively
>     investigating. Further updates will be published to keep you apprised
>     of the situation.

I need my web application and SQL database to be UP all the time, for the customers sake.

Having the website replicated in two different zones is easy: I just need to deploy the website to two different zones, eg. West US and East US.

The question is...
**How can I have my SQL Database replicated in two different zones?**

Notice that I'm not worried about the website database connection string, I can change that and re-deploy. That would put down the website for 3 seconds, but thats OK. Now my website has been down for more than 40 minutes! (not OK)

Also, if there are other better ideas (rather than replicating the database in two zones), please answer with them. They can override my question if necesary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel your pain, I have been there before. What you need is the Azure Geo-Replication in the new database tiers http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2014/05/01/azure-sql-database-new-service-tiers-q-amp-a.aspx

Unfortunately the version you (and I) best need is only available to Premium and cost lots and lots of money!

There is also a version in Standard but they have a weird policy where they leave you to cry in your soup for an hour as customers complain before you can switch to the replica.

Comment: what about having my own sql server in a virtual machine? instead of using the "azure sql server"

Comment: so if my database today is "web edition", how do I upgrade to "premium"?, I went to my database (Azure management portal), then "Scale", and there, only two options are shown: "web" and "business". And after upgrading to premium the geo redundancy is automatic?

Comment: I think the upgrade ability is coming in the next week or so.